# Page and Page Content Type and Life Cycle

Tags: content-type, page-layout

How is a Page and Page Content Type related to each other? And is this question even relevant. If not, then do explain with a simple example.

And what does life cycle means in SharePoint. For example:  Web Part Life Cycle and Page Life Cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regarding Content Types for publishing**

if you have Article pages and you want to add an additional image field to all Article pages, you can do this by modifying the Article Page content type, which makes the field available to use as a page-layout element. Any pages to which the content type is applied will be able to use the new field.

You should be aware of that There are six content types that have the Publishing feature enabled. The following shows each type,

- Article Page
- Redirect Page
- Welcome Page
- Publishing Master Page
- Page
- Page Layout

For more details check [About publishing-enabled content types](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/About-publishing-enabled-content-types-40bffc50-7e05-4d27-8c42-d025e99a0518)

**Regarding Web part Life Cycle.**

Like Asp.Net life cycle there is also Web Part and page life cycle.

the following events show the web part life cycle

- OnInit: This method handles initialization of the control.
- OnLoad: This event handles the Load event. This is also used for initializing the control but is not intended for loading data or other processing functionality.
- CreateChildControls: This is the most popular event in web part life cycle. This creates any child controls. So if you are adding any control to display then you have to write in this method.
- EnsureChildControls: This method ensures that CreateChildControls has executed. EnsureChildControls method must be called to prevent null reference exceptions.
- SaveViewState: View state of the web part saved.
- OnPreRender: This method handles or initiates tasks such as data loading that must complete before the control can render.
- Page.PreRenderComplete: The page fires the PreRenderComplete event after all controls have completed their OnPreRender methods.
- Render: This method is used to render everything.
- RenderContents: Renders the contents of the control only, inside of the outer tags and style properties.
- OnUnload: Performs the final cleanup.

For more details check https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/guruketepalli/2011/11/29/visual-web-part-life-cycle/